# How can I calculate time complexity of this recursion algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

How can I calculate time complexity of following piece of code? Suppose m is close to n. What I got is f(n) = 2*f(n-1). So time complexity is f(n) = O(2^n). Am I right?

```
int uniquePaths(int m, int n) {
    if (m < 1 || n < 1) return 0;
    if (m == 1 && n == 1) return 1;
    return uniquePaths(m - 1, n) + uniquePaths(m, n - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some hand-waving involved in what follows, but I think it's essentially correct.

Every leaf in the call tree will contribute 1 to the total result, so the number of leaves is uniquePaths(m,n). Since uniquePaths(m,n) == "m+n-2 choose n-1", when m and n are similar the execution time of your algorithm will be roughly the central binomial coefficient "2n choose n", which is in O(4^n).